# Can't select app version to test on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, beta-testing

I was having problem with uploading a build of my app but I was successful uploading a build (0.0.7) of version (1.0.0) while the build (0.0.6) was still processing
[image: I was able to upload o.o.7 as shown in this screenshot]

But when I am trying to add internal testers to test this build, the uploaded version is not showing up instead it shows the version which is still in processing.

[image: Build number 0.0.7 not showing up]

Does it have something to do with iTunes or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: "Thank you for providing that information. In reviewing the information you provided, I can see that you have a build that is stuck in processing and you were able to upload subsequent builds successfully, however you are unable to test the new builds.

We’ve had some reports of this issue and it should now be resolved. In order to continue testing, you will need to submit a new build with a new version. Once you submit a new build with a new version, you will have the new builds available to select from when choosing a build to test."
Response from Apple Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A guy from Apple contacted me after 12 hours with this e-mail

"Thank you for providing that information. In reviewing the information and screenshots you provided, I can see that you have a build that is stuck in processing and you were able to upload subsequent builds successfully, however you are unable to test the new builds.

We’ve had some reports of this issue and it should now be resolved. In order to continue testing, you will need to submit a new build with a new version. Once you submit a new build with a new version, you will have the new builds available to select from when choosing a build to test."

So, I think uploading a new build with a new version will hopefully work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by logging into iTunes Connect and removing myself as an internal tester (which removed the app from my TestFlight App) and then accepting the invitation again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
1) Launch Application Loader.
2) In the top menu bar, click Application Loader > Preferences.
3) Choose Advanced.
4) Under Transfer Protocol, deselect Aspera.
5) Close the Preferences window and proceed with the delivery.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue and i change the version of my app in Xcode and then it will be shown in the internal testing. Please just change the version of your app then it will show. Just change the version to 1.0.1 or 1.1 whatever you want. Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Regards

Mandeep Singh